# Symfony2 - how to construct id = product mapping

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I want to do mapping that does this:

**User** can own multiple **Games**. **Games** can have multiple **owners**.

I have `id` column in `game` table and `game` and `user` columns in `ownership` table. How I can connect these fields? I want to have `game` and `user` fields in `ownership` related to `user` and `game` tables.

I tried `OneToMany` and `ManyToMany`, but the first one results in generating additional columns. I **don't** want to insert anything in `game` table.

--edit--
My @ManyToMany code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Ownership")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="ownership",
 *      joinColumns={JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={JoinColumn(name="game", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
```

It causes an error in Symfony's command line:

```
  [Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]                            
  [Semantical Error] Couldn't find constant JoinColumn, property GameShelf\Us  
  ersBundle\Entity\User::$ownership.
```

Comment: Supposing this code is in your `User` entity, the `targetEntity` should be `Game`, not `Ownership`. Try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you need many to many relations if, like you said:

> User can own multiple Games. Games can have multiple owners.

The Doctrine should create third table (which could contains only two foreign keys: game_id and ownership_id).

The error is caused because Doctrine dosen't know what `JoinColumn` is. You just did wrong annotation because you forgot (again! ;)) precede `JoinColumn` with `@ORM. The right annotation should look like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Ownership")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="ownership",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="game", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
```

Comment: Heh, I make this mistake over and over again. Thanks for this. But - if I want many relations (let's say `users` to `rates`, `ownership`, `games` to `ownership`, `rates`, `genres` etc), woudn't there be too many tables (`games_rates`, `games_genres`)? Woudn't this be quite messy?

Comment: In fact you don't have any choice if you want keep MANY-TO-MANY relations. And don't worry - it wouldn't be messy because of that.

Comment: Oooookay, I get it. But then, when I'll have a lot of these tables, how would I print those informations in one place? Multiple joins? I know too little about Doctrine and SQL to imagine this properly.

Comment: What do you mean by "print those informations in one place" ? You can retrieve your data through entities (like eg. $game->getOwnership()->getEmail() ) or through queries that you'll create in your repositories. The things will get more clear after you read symfony's documentations and play with it for some time (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html). The other very helpful thing could be look at projects based on symfony 2 on the github (there are a lot of them, just google it)

Comment: What makes you think I didn't read the docs before posting here? I did read the docs, did the examples from there couple of times to get a good grip of how it works. So I wanted to make something similar, and it seems that either no one really understands what I am talking about, or what I achieved earlier in CodeIgniter and in MySQL using PDO (and in clean MySQL obviosly) can't be done in Symfony2 withot making n additional tables in the database.

Comment: I dont understand why these additional tables is problem for you. It doesn't matter if you use Doctrine or PDO - if you want realize many-to-many relation you NEED this third table. There is no better way in relational db if you want keep 3NF.

Comment: And I understand it. It's not a problem, more something like concern that the database will grow full of relational tables. But nevermind that, I know too little about this to argue (which I'm not, I'm just saying). But let's suppose, I want to show current user's owned games (so three tables are already in play - `games`, `ownership` and `user_ownership`). I also want to display his rate for the game (another two tables - `rates` and `user_rates`). Is it okay? And if yes - how? I do `join` all the time?

Comment: It's completely ok to have three tables for two entities and many-to-many information for them, don't worry. But if we speak about "joins" you can use them to get information OR get all data through keys (which means you will have more queries, but it's gain advantage if you arrange some cache layer like memcache or redis). There are pros and cons for both ways, and you just have read about it. But from here I can say that "join's way" will be totally fine for you for now.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to introduce a new entity (something like OwnedGame) that holds the connection between a Game and an Owner (and possibly its own properties like when it was bought and such).

Then OwnedGame would be ManyToOne with Game and with Owner, and neither Game nor Owner would need to include a new column.

Comment: Is it necessary? I mean, with pure MySQL it isn't. And when I will want to enlarge the project, bring ratings etc, I will be forced to create number of entities. I'm looking for solving this with neither creating too much additional columns nor creating additional entities.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of what you want doesn't fit at all.
On the one hand you want to have a relation between only Users and Games, and only between Games and Owners.

But on the other hand you say that Users and Owners are related in some way, but Games and Users aren't.

You should read through
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional
and try to find what you really need.
I would recommend a ManyToMany relation with a join table. Thus you don't have to deal with additional fields in your tables

Comment: Uhm, user = owner :) I've made a doodle to demonstrate: http://i.imagebanana.com/img/k25rnzk4/Beznazwy1.gif

also, I tried the code from the docs (modified it to "work" with Symfony) and I got errors. Check my edited question

Comment: You forgot to put 

    @ORM\
 
in front of 
`JoinColumn`